# Why would a mod return zero when it's restricted to <=1?

Tags: c, random, linked-list, malloc, function-pointers

```
Card *createCard() {

  /* This function dynamically allocates a new Card struct object and returns a 
  pointer to that struct object which will later be used to insert into a 
  linked list. There are three types of cards ATTACK, DEFEND, and RUN. 
  ATTACK and DEFEND cards also have a value. 
  You will assign a card type based on these random chances:
    40% - ATTACK: the value is a random number between 1 and 5 inclusive.
    50% - DEFEND: the value is a random number between 3 and 8 inclusive.
    10% - RUN: the value is a random number between 1 and 8 inclusive. 
    The value of a RUN card is only used for sorting purposes.*/
    
    Card *createdCard;
    int n;
    int v; 
    createdCard = (Card *)malloc(sizeof(Card));
    
    n = (rand() % 10) + 1;
    
    if (n == 1) {
        createdCard->cardType = RUN;
        v = (rand() % 8) + 1;
        createdCard->value = v;
    }
    else if (n > 1 && n < 7) {
        createdCard->cardType = DEFEND;
        v = (rand() % 6) + 3;
        createdCard->value = v;
    }
    else if (n > 6 && n < 10) {
        createdCard->cardType = ATTACK;
        v = ( rand() % 5) + 1;
        createdCard->value = v;
    }
    
    createdCard->next = NULL;
    
    return createdCard;
}
```

[image: Output with A0 and should be 1 through 5]

Comment: You miss the case when `n == 10`. Use an `else` (without `if`) instead.

Comment: mod will return zero when first operands is divisible by second operands. And what does `it's restricted to <=1` mean?

Comment: `n<10` --> `n<=10`

Comment: What specifically returns 0 here? 0 is <=1 by the way.

Comment: I think the OP mean it's `>=1` (because of the `+1`). They thought `(rand()%10)+1` was resulting in zero (but in fact, they were getting `10`)

Comment: [not the cause of the problem] `rand() %10` is not unbiased.

Answer (score 1):

By the statement

```
n = (rand()%10)+1;
```

An integer from 1 to 10 (both inclusive) will be assigned to `n`.

`n == 1` will be come true when `n` is `1`.

`n>1 && n<7` will become true when `n` is one of `2, 3, 4, 5, 6`.

`n>6 && n<10` will become true when `n` is one of `7, 8, 9`.

Therefore, no assignment to `createdCard->cardType` and `createdCard->value` will performed and their value will remain *indeterminate* when `n` is `10`.

If you use the indeterminate value, you will invoke *undefined behavior* and it seems you got zero by chance.

To resolve this issue, you should add `else` statement to cover `n = 10` case and assign values to `createdCard->cardType` and `createdCard->value`.

Comment: YES!This corrected the issue! else
 {
        createdCard->cardType = ATTACK;
        v = ( rand() %5)+1;
        createdCard->value = v;
    }

Answer (score 1):

Suppose `rand()` returns `9` here:

`n = (rand()%10)+1;`

Then `n` will be `10`.

But there is no conditional statement that handles that case. This will likely cause `createdCard->value` to be `0` because it hasn't been initialized, and because free memory is sparse.

This will also happen when rand returns 19, 29, 39, 49, ... I e 10% of the time

Comment: Yes this was the issue! thank you for the help and for explaining the error.

Comment: now I'm receiving a segmentation fault(memory dump)???

Comment: Just make a new question